# How to pass a string from a php variable into an xml request?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I probably composed my question very stupidly, but I did the best I could, I apologize in advance)

I have an XML file.
I need to run a query like this:

```
$xml->shop->offers->offer
```

The problem is that I get this path from a variable:

```
$path = 'shop->offers->offer'
```

But it won't work like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.com');
$exampleElement = $xml->$path;
```

How can I fix the code so it works?

Comment: Split the string into an array using explode. Then use a loop to get each nested property using that list.

Comment: Have a look at XPath as it uses something similar.

Comment: @barmar, Could you show with an example? I'll split the array, but how can I use foreach in this query? `$path = explode( "->", $path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the path, then loop over it getting each nested property.

```
$props = explode("->", $path);
$el = $xml;
foreach ($props as $prop) {
    $el = $el->$prop;
}
var_dump($el);
```